# get DM Message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have this code

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import DMChannel
TOKEN = "bot token"
client = Bot (command_prefix='!')
@client.command(name='dm', pass_context=True)
async def dmsend(ctx):
    user = await client.fetch_user("user ID")
    await DMChannel.send(user, "Hello there!")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

which basically sends a specific user a message if the user writes !dm. However is there a way to do it via dms? So everytime I receive a message with **!dm** under my dms it will excecute it in the `#general` channel?

Comment: You want the user to be able to use the command `dmsend` in the DMs of the bot and if the user does that the output should be sent to a `#general` chat? I do not really get your question(s)

Comment: exactly that is my question @Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some constraints and make your code simpler in some places.

**First:** Use `@commands.dm_only()` and thus ensure or only allow that the command is executed in the private messages.

**Second:** How you query the author of the message is a bit complicated and a `fetch` should not be used for this, because otherwise you might get a rate limit. The best way is to use the following: `user = ctx.author`

**Third:** To define a `general` channel or something else you can use `client.get_channel(ChannelID)`

**Have a look at the full code:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.dm_only() # Can only be used in the bots DMs
async def dmsend(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await user.send("Hello there!") # Send a DM to the author of the command
    general = client.get_channel(ChannelID) # Define the general channel
    await general.send(f"Sent a DM to {ctx.author}") # Your text after a DM
```

*Also see the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=dm_only#discord.ext.commands.dm_only) for more information*

Comment: Hey um also a question for something else I planned. Is there a way to copy the message the user seant me? Would really appreciate an answer

Comment: @Haider You can open another question for that. More or other things have to be taken into account